# How do I set up an exception to an Exchange mail flow rule for "trusted" senders?

Tags: office365, exchange, rules

I've recently set up a new mail flow rule in our Exchange (365) admin center to prepend a "warning" banner to the body of e-mail messages received from external senders. I've defined it like this (**Exchange Admin Center -> Mail Flow -> Rules -> [+] New rule**)
[image: EAC Mail Flow Rule Definition]

However, as with most changes made for the sake of security, there's been a bit of push-back ("it's annoying", etc.). Even so, in and amongst the standard complaints, there was actually an excellent point raised: If ***all*** external messages - which make up a significant majority of the e-mail communication that our users receive - are flagged with this warning, it will eventually become so ubiquitous that the users will simply start to ignore it. The warning will no longer serve its intended purpose because the users have seen it in virtually every message they receive, including messages sent from those senders they know and trust.

Based on this feedback, I started looking into the exception options available for the Exchange mail flow rules. I see that there are a number of possibilities in there, including exceptions for explicitly defined senders, domains, and IP addresses; keywords; and even specific message properties. However, one thing that I've not found which I think would be useful is to base the exception on some server-side whitelist.

Here, I'm talking about something separate from the "main" whitelist that prevents certain messages from being flagged as spam. My first thought was to use the recipient's "Safe Senders" list from Outlook, although, as I've thought about it, I can see some potential dangers in using that, even if it *would* make the management of such a list much less cumbersome for myself.

Looking at the available options in the "New Rule" dialog, the only other thing I've been able to come up with as a possibility is for me to create a new Exchange group into which I (manually) enter any and all senders/domains that should be "whitelisted". I'm not *totally* against this as an option, but getting the list "right" will likely take some time. Also, perhaps I'm being dense, but I'm honestly not entirely sure ***how*** to go about doing this effectively.

As I stated above, most of the e-mail communication with our company is from external senders, so any "whitelist" is likely to be fairly long. Additionally, I realize that such a list has the potential to inadvertently open things up to "spoofing" attacks, so I'm trying to be thoughtful about how I would implement it to minimize that threat. At this point, I'm really just looking for suggestions from experienced Exchange admins who may have already encountered this "issue" and found a way to implement a reasonable and relatively secure solution.

---

### EDIT/UPDATE

In my ongoing research, I came across an article ([Create safe sender lists in EOP](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/office-365-security/create-safe-sender-lists-in-office-365?view=o365-worldwide)) that includes what seems like at least a small part of the answer. One exception I can include is a check of the message headers for a valid sender authentication status of the sending email domain to ensure that the sending domain is not being spoofed.

- **Mail flow rule condition: A message header > includes any of these
  words > Header name:** `Authentication-Results` **> Header Value:**
  `dmarc=pass` **OR** `dmarc=bestguesspass`

As an alternative (if it became necessary), I could also research the MX records of the sending domains manually and find the appropriate IP address(es) to set up an exception for those:

- **IP Allow List:** Specify the source IP address or address range in the connection filter policy.

Something like this could help to at least reduce the number of messages "flagged" with the warning banner.

However, my thought on this is that the rules don't give you an option to choose between **AND** and **OR** conditions. For example, if I want a rule to explicitly check the sender against a whitelist of specific senders, domains, or IP addresses (depending on how I have to set it up, I imagine these could end up in three separate lists somewhere), then ALSO check the message headers, I'd need my exception rule to look something like this:

- (**Sender address in** *[address whitelist]* **OR Sender domain in** *[domain whitelist]* **OR Sender IP in** *[IP whitelist]*) **AND** (**Message header includes** `dmarc=pass` **OR Message header includes** `dmarc=bestguesspass`)

I don't currently see any way to make something like this happen in the mail flow rule interface. Maybe I'm overthinking it, but isn't that what we do? :P

Comment: I'm beginning to wonder if it's safe to assume at this point that either nobody else is going to these lengths, or nobody has figured out a way to do what I'm trying to do? I'd like to think that it's possible, even if there's a significant amount of work to be done to accomplish the goal but, if not, I guess I'll have to forego the warning for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

Although the or and and options are not included in a rule, you can create multiple rules to implement the or option.

Comment: Thank you for the useful information but, unfortunately, it doesn't really seem to answer the central question of setting up a "trusted senders" exception.

Comment: As you mentioned above, it is possible to create a group to whitelist external senders, but to achieve this, you must first create contacts for these external senders in your organization, only then you can create groups for them.

But there is another way, instead of creating groups, manually add them to the exception conditions, here's a similar thread for your reference: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2280836-how-do-i-set-up-an-exception-to-an-exchange-mail-flow-rule-for-trusted-senders?page=1#entry-8927476

Comment: Thank you. It looks like I've got a fair amount of work ahead of me if I want to implement such a list, but it *might* be worth it in the long term. The work may have to wait a bit since I have some other projects, but I'll try to come back and update this question once I've had a chance to implement it and do some testing. If you'd like to update your answer with the information from this comment, I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: After my further research, since the complexity of the issue, and the support resource limit in my environment,  and if you are urgent, I suggest you refer to the following link and open a ticket, the engineers will provide professional support with you. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4051701/global-customer-service-phone-numbers

Comment: Thank you. The issue is not urgent. At this point, I'm just *considering* doing something about it but, in the meantime, I'm just going to leave the feature disabled until I can actually spend some time implementing a legitimate solution. Perhaps, if there's a way to do so, I could provide this as a "suggestion" to the Exchange team at Microsoft...

Comment: UserVoice seems to be a good place:) https://office365.uservoice.com/